# Powering Off RPI when on UPS

Tags: power-management

Is there any way by which I can power off RPI2 when system is on UPS after sometime **using software only**. My UPS communicates with the system using USB. But it has windows support. I want to have similar mechanism with RPI2.

I'm using this [UPS model](http://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B00B2LA6H8?psc=1&redirect=true&ref_=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00).

Thank You.

Comment: May be more info on UPS model how it gets connected to windows could be useful.

Comment: I believe that you can download its source from this site : http://www.apcupsd.com and follow this instructions to compile and run it on Rpi. : https://code.google.com/p/quickanddirty/wiki/APCinLinux Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dastaan. I will follow the steps. I will update this thread with my findings.

Comment: @dastaan - `apcupsd` is the answer I would have provided - can you turn your comment into an answer with a little more explanation?

Comment: @PhilB. Added. :)

Answer (score 2):

I think for this particular UPS, vendor also provides source on their [site](http://www.apcupsd.com).

You can download source from this [link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/apcupsd/files/apcupsd%20-%20Stable/3.14.13/apcupsd-3.14.13.tar.gz/download).

Untar it and copy it on Raspberry pi.

And as per this [guide](https://code.google.com/p/quickanddirty/wiki/APCinLinux),

1. Install dependencies by `sudo apt-get install libgd2-xpm-dev libusb-dev`
2. cd to source directory.
3. `./configure --enable-usb --enable-cgi`
4. Once configuration done, `make && sudo make install` to compile and install binaries.
5. To test, run : `apcaccess`

I didn't test it but it should ideally work.

Hope it helps. :)